# Couchdb: Show _attachments

Tags: couchdb

Just getting a feel for CouchDB and hitting a few misunderstanding.

I can list the records from a view with (thanks to a previous responder)

```
http://mysite.iriscouch.com/mydb/_design/_view/myview
```

I have amended my view to include _attachments, but that does not appear to be showing the _attachments, which are jpeg files.

```
map
function(doc) {
  if(doc.SignMark && doc.Details) {
    emit(doc.SignMark, doc.Details, doc._attachments);
  }
}
```

I have obviously missed some simple concept

Thanks - mcl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emit always takes two parameters: key and value. Each can be an object. So this would work:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.SignMark && doc.Details) {
    emit(doc.SignMark, [doc.Details, doc._attachments]);
 }
}
```

But you can construct arbitrary keys and values to emit, and you can also emit multiple or no values at all for each document.

The excellent [CouchDB Book](http://guide.couchdb.org/index.html) helped me a lot! This is the relevant chapter for views: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html

Comment: Many thanks.  I have printed that chapter out and will read it over my dinner later. Unfortunately your suggestion works, but it lists the metadata of the attachment and not the actual jpeg image.  Is it possible to show the image, when executing the view as an http request in the browser address bar ?  I am using the browser address bar, as a means of quickly understanding basic functionality.

Comment: You are viewing the JSON data, which is more or less a string. If you want to see the document as a HTML page, then you should write a show function that you can use to format your document nicely (or a list function which can output a view result nicely): http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/show.html

Comment: There isn't a way to view binary data + JSON data. MapReduce View functions only return a JSON document. Bernhard mentioned the show function which would allow you to write an HTML UI for individual documents. However, in this case, you may want to consider building a List function: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html It's similar to Show, but uses View results for its input rather than a single document. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

From within a view you cannot access the attachments themselves. You can only the metadata which is stored in the doc._attachments.

So depending on your requirements, you will have to access the actual attachment with a second request of the format  /db/doc-id/attachment-name.jpg

or, if you are rendering to html, just construct an image tag with the src='/db/doc-id/attachment-name.jpg'

Comment: How do i get the attachment key/name using views?